# Offline installer for .net 3.5 sp1 not working

Tags: .net, windows-server-2012, .net-3.5

I download a big file of .Net 3.5 SP1 from http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe

Now when I try to install it on Windows Server 2012, I get the following screenshot:

[image]

What the?? When will the microsoft learn?

Now this is a loop. When I try to install from Server Manager, I get installation cannot be done. It needs installation disk.

Does that mean I can't install at all without the installation disk in presence?

Comment: Note: cross-posted on Stack Overflow at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192244/offline-installer-for-net-3-5-sp1-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

In an elevated Windows PowerShell command window, run the following command:

```
Install-WindowsFeature –name NET-Framework-Core –source <drive>:\sources\sxs
```

Note In this command,  is a placeholder for the drive letter for the DVD drive or for the Windows installation media. For example, you run the following command:

```
Install-WindowsFeature –name NET-Framework-Core –source D:\sources\sxs
```

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2734782/en-us)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about Win2k12, but on 2k8 it's .net framework is available under server features.

Run Server management, go to Features, and .net 3.5 is right there.

I bet that's why it's failing.

Comment: Didn't work. The actual answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192244/offline-installer-for-net-3-5-sp1-not-working

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Server 2012/R2, you don't have to download the 3.5 version of the .NET Framework; instead, you'll have to install it as a Windows feature, from Server Manager.

If the Server Manager complains about not being able to find the installation sources, you'll need to add the Windows installation DVD (or ISO) as an installation source.